# Vue.js project using Vue I18n has got the following error: "TypeError: i18n is undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vue-cli-3, vue-i18n

I'm trying to add internationalization on my Vue.js project using Vue I18n.

I'm using the documentation (i.e. http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/sfc.html#basic-usage), but I've got the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: i18n is undefined"

found in

---> <MainNavBar> at src/components/MainNavBar.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619 

TypeError: "i18n is undefined"
    $t vue-i18n.esm.js:167
    render MainNavBar.vue:33
    VueJS 42
    <anonymous> main.js:18
    js app.js:6991
    __webpack_require__ app.js:724
    fn app.js:101
    0 app.js:7304
    __webpack_require__ app.js:724
    <anonymous> app.js:791
    <anonymous> app.js:1 vue.runtime.esm.js:1887
    VueJS 45
    <anonymous> main.js:18
    js app.js:6991
    __webpack_require__ app.js:724
    fn app.js:101
    0 app.js:7304
    __webpack_require__ app.js:724
    <anonymous> app.js:791
    <anonymous> app.js:1
```

I don't understand why i18n is "undefined", because I've installed it through NPM as it is shown in documentation.

Could someone help me?

I've already tried to look for a solution on the internet, but without success.

In order to help in this question, I send below the code that I use.

Thank you in advance.

**MainNavBar.vue**

```
<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "home": "Home"
  },
  "pt": {
    "home": "Início"
  }
}
</i18n>

<template>
  ...
  <li class="nav-item">
    <router-link class="nav-link" to='/home'>
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i> {{ $t('home') }}
    </router-link>
  </li>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      locale: 'en'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    locale (val) {
      this.$i18n.locale = val
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueI18n)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**vue.config.js**

```
const merge = require('deepmerge')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options =>
        merge(options, {
          loaders: {
            i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'
          }
        })
      )
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "executive_frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
    "ol": "^5.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.7",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.10.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.6",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "deepmerge": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/dev/examples/sfc/src/main.js. I guessed you should add i18n in new Vue().

Comment: Yes, I believe that you are right, however I would like to separate the "messages" inside the component as it is shown in the documentation. In your code the "messages" is inside the i18n. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass an i18n instance to the Vue constructor.

This is the instance

```
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: "en", // set default locale
    messages: {
        en: { // object with messages },
        fr: { // another locale messages }
    },
})
```

and pass it here

```
new Vue({
    i18n,
    router,
    ...
})
```

Comment: console.log(`i18n ${this.$i18n}`) // print undefined

Answer (score 0):

Watchers has no context. You should use method instead:

```
<template>
  <select @change="update">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="es">Español</option>
    <option value="ru">Русский</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    update(e) {
      this.i18n.locale = e.target.value
    }
  }
}
</script>
```